# Sql Query to get the values based on % of input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table like below

```
 Board Component Cost

    b1     c1       5
    b1     c2       10
    b2     c3       15
    b3     c4       20
    b3     c5       25
    b4     C6       25
  ---------------------
                  100%
```

I shoud give the input to get the values from the table, say...

If the input is 20%

the output should be

```
 Board Component Cost

    b1      c1      5
    b1      c2     10
    b2      c3     15
```

If the input is 50%

the output should be

```
 Board Component Cost

    b1      c1      5
    b1      c2     10
    b2      c3     15
    b3      c4     20
```

and so on

How to write the query in sql server

Comment: With 50%, why not the last two? We should select from up to down ?

Comment: Shouldn't 20% be 30%? Do you want to sum parts until you reach certain percentage?

Comment: what do you want to order by?

Comment: This sounds like the subset sum problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Yes, First i need to order by then from low to high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 INT, SumValue Int)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b1','c1',5)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b1','c2',10)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b2','c3',15)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b3','c4',20)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b3','c5',25)

INSERT INTO @T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('b4','C6',25) 

DECLARE @SumValue INT

UPDATE @T
SET @SumValue=SumValue = ISNULL(@SumValue,0)+ Col3
FROM @T T

SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE SumValue <= (
    SELECT TOP 1 SumValue
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE T.SumValue>=40
    ORDER BY SumValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, since we need to group and sum previous values, you will need an Identity to implement this.
I hope you can come up with one.
I created this table to simulate your situation:

```
create table mySUM(
id int identity(1,1),
id2 varchar(50),
cost int)

insert into mySUM values
('c1',  5),   ('b1', 10),    ('b2',15),    ('b3',20),    ('b3',25),    ('b4',25)
```

I have two selects to you.
This is the main one but, since we are grouping and summing, it will result the sum on the last column:

```
select a.Id, a.id2, sum(b.cost) as totalCost
from mySUM a cross join mySUM b
where b.Id <= a.Id
group by a.Id,a.id2
having sum(b.cost)<=50
order by  a.Id
```

result:

```
1   c1  5
2   b1  15
3   b2  30
4   b3  50
```

if you dont want that, you can run a select on the main table based on the ids of the above select:

```
select * from mySUM where id in(
    select a.Id
    from mySUM a cross join mySUM b
    where b.Id <= a.Id
    group by a.Id,a.id2
    having sum(b.cost)<=50
)
```

result:

```
1   c1  5
2   b1  10
3   b2  15
4   b3  20
```

Comment: If its 50% it will list all. however it should not, please check the second output table

Comment: yes, I did read too fast. I changed my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT  t.* ,
        rt.runningTotal
FROM    Test t
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(cost) AS runningTotal
                      FROM      Test
                      WHERE     Board <= t.Board
                                AND Component <= t.Component
                    ) AS rt
WHERE   runningTotal <= 50
ORDER BY t.Board
```

Comment: When asking for 20% in your question you return 5+10+15 = 30. Shouldn't this be 5+10=15 since that's smaller then 20?

Comment: Change The inner Where clause if you need them ordered by Score. The original question was not clear on that and though you wanted to sorted alphabetically on the first 2 columns.

Comment: @Somashekhar Maybe you could help your helpers by stating what is not correct

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with CTE (Board, Component ,Cost, rownum)
as
(
SELECT Board,Component, Cost,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by Cost asc, Board asc, Component asc) rownum
  FROM yourTable t0
  where Cost > 0
)
select
t1.Board,t1.Component, t1.Cost, t1.rownum, sum(t2.Cost)
from 
CTE t1 join CTE t2 on t1.rownum >= t2.rownum
group by t1.Board,t1.Component, t1. Cost, t1.rownum
having sum(t2.Cost) < 50
order by t1.rownum;
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #per(
Board varchar(10),
Component varchar(max),
Cost int)

create proc out_per (
@desire_per int)
as begin

declare @sum int, @count int;
declare @board varchar(max), @component varchar(max);
declare @cost int;
declare per_cursor cursor for
select Board,Component,Cost from per
open per_cursor
fetch next from per_cursor into @Board, @component, @cost
while(@@fetch_status=0)
    begin
        insert into #per values (@Board, @component, @cost);
        set @sum=(select sum(cost) from #per)
        if(@sum>=@desire_per)
        begin
            break;
        end
        fetch next from per_cursor into @Board, @component, @cost
    end
    close per_cursor
    deallocate per_cursor
    select * from #per
    truncate table #per
end

exec out_per @desire_per=30
```